# Why do only arithmetic operations print out a value and not a normal one

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main(){

    float arr[5] = {12.5, 10.0, 13.5, 90.5, 0.5};
    float *ptr1 = &arr[0];
    float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    printf("%f ", *ptr2); // outputs 90.5  
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);  // outputs 3
    printf("%d",ptr2) ;

   return 0;
}
```

why the last line doesn't print 3 instead of some random value

Comment: 3 looks pretty random to me. ([here](https://www.random.org/analysis/dilbert.jpg)).

Comment: Is `3` less "random" than  `125`? And where is it specified it should be random at all?

Comment: 3 is not random its getting subtracted you can change the value and add it to  ptr2 and check

Comment: Third line prints the address of ptr2.. it won't print 3.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar It can print anything, as specifying `%d` with a pointer is UB.

Comment: thts what my question is then why it is not printing the address in the second print statement

Comment: Your question wording is not matching the code comments.

Comment: @downtown.. In second print your are taking the address difference of ptr2 and ptr1

Comment: @Rajeshkumar how does it prints the index only after an airthmatic operation why does it returns the index in the last one whts the difference?

Comment: There is no "airthmatic" word in English. There is "arithmetic". I though it is typo, but you keep writing it.

Comment: Read about undefined behaviour and read the `printf` man-page (and the documenation of other functions you use) before asking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry i will correct my spelling thank you for that

Comment: @Eugene 3 is definitely more random than 42.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the fundamentals of [c](/questions/tagged/c). `ptr1` could be expressed as either `ptr1 = &arr[0]` or `ptr1 = arr`: both forms are equivalent. Additionally, your `ptr2` assignment could be expressed as either `ptr2 = ptr1 +3` or as `ptr2 = &ptr1[3]`.

The line in question:

```
printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
```

Subtracts one pointer value from another, and results in the number of "gaps" between the two pointers, assuming that each "gap" is the size of a `float`.

The example below should provide more insight. The use of the `intptr_t` type is just so that I can manipulate a pointer as if it were a simple number.

## Code Listing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define OFFSET  (3)

int main(void)
{
    float arr[5] = {12.5, 10.0, 13.5, 90.5, 0.5};
    float *ptr1 = &arr[0];
    float *ptr2 = ptr1 + OFFSET;

    printf("%p %p\n", ptr1, ptr2);
    printf("sizeof(float):%ld\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("Distance between pointers (bytes):%ld\n", (intptr_t)ptr2 - (intptr_t)ptr1);
    printf("Distance between pointers (gaps):%ld\n", ptr2 - ptr1);


    return 0;
}
```

## Sample Run

```
0x7fffdc244800 0x7fffdc24480c
sizeof(float):4
Distance between pointers (bytes):12
Distance between pointers (gaps):3
```

If you haven't already, I strongly recommend you buy/rent/borrow a copy of "C Primer Plus" by Prata, and do all the exercises in the chapters and the quizzes at the end. This very topic is covered at length early on in the book, and in great detail.

Comment: thank you for the recommend

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of what's happening on each printing line, with corrections:

```
printf("%f ", *ptr2);
```

This line outputs `90.5`, which is the value pointed to by `*(ptr1 + 3)`, which is the same as `ptr1[3]`.

```
printf("%td", ptr2 - ptr1);
```

This line should use `%td` because the result of subtracting `ptr1` from `ptr2` produces a result of type `ptrdiff_t`. The result is the number of positions in the array of `float`s between `ptr2` and `ptr1`, which is `3`.

Note that this works because both pointers are pointing into the same array; you cannot subtract just any two arbitrary pointers and get a well-defined answer. Subtracting pointers that are not pointing into the same array is undefined behavior.

```
printf("%p", (void*)ptr2) ;
```

This line prints a numeric value of the pointer. You need to use `%p` instead of `%d`. Using `%d` produces undefined behavior, which in your case results in printing 3. Using `%p` and converting the pointer to `void*` fix undefined behavior; [the result printed on ideone is different](https://ideone.com/tFQwc6).

> How does it prints the index only after an arithmetic operation? Why does it returns the index in the last one? What's the difference?

C has special rules that apply to arithmetic operations on pointers, called *pointer arithmetic*.

A pointer by itself is not an index. However, you can add an integer to a pointer, and C will treat it as moving a pointer by the corresponding number of indexes to the right or to the left, depending on the sign of the integer. Moreover, C defines pointer subtraction in terms of the number of indexes, so the usual rules of arithmetic apply:

```
(p + i) - p = i
```